# Assigning gradient using JS fails on dynamically generated gradient

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, dom-events, radial-gradients

Assigning a gradient to an HTML element fails, if the string of CSS is generated in JS on runtime, but it does not if it's a string defined as constant. I want to generate a radial-gradient at the position of the cursor, but I simplified this example to only contain the lines of code required to cause the unwanted behaviour.

HTML:

```
<div class=buggy-gradient></div>
<div class=buggy-gradient></div>
<div class=buggy-gradient></div>
```

JS (not working):

```
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('buggy-gradient');

for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
  divs.item(i).addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    let gradient = 'radial-gradient(circle at ' + e.clientX + ' ' + e.clientY + ', blue, red)';
    console.log(gradient);
    e.target.style.background = gradient;
  });
}
```

The console-log shows the CSS line as I want it, but assigning it apparently fails:

> "radial-gradient(circle at 1044 325, blue, red)"

JS (working):

```
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('buggy-gradient');

for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
  divs.item(i).addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    e.target.style.background = 'radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, blue, red)';
  });
}
```

I made a pen: https://codepen.io/stairjoke/pen/poNgKbm

As a Stack Snippet:

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('buggy-gradient');

for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
  divs.item(i).addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    let gradient = 'radial-gradient(circle at ' + e.clientX + ' ' + e.clientY + ', blue, red)';
    console.log(gradient);
    e.target.style.background = gradient;
    // e.target.style.background = 'radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, blue, red)';
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background: radial-gradient(green, yellow);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class=buggy-gradient></div>
<div class=buggy-gradient></div>
<div class=buggy-gradient></div>
```

Comment: *"I made a pen"* Please put your runnable example **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Thanks. *(I've copied it for you this time, although I'm not really supposed to do that because of licensing...)*

Comment: (Side note: If you're not declaring `i` in code you haven't shown, beware that that code falls prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). :-) )

Comment: When I run the snippet, I definitely see the gradient moving around, but probably not in the way you meant it to. I *suspect* that it's because `clientX` and `clientY` are relative to the viewport, but in `radial-gradient` they're relative to the `background-position`. But I haven't played with gradients enough to post an answer, it's just a suspicion.

Comment: Interesting, what browser are you using? For me Safari doesn't show the blue-red gradient, only the CSS yellow-green fallback. Update: Also tried in Firefox, still only see the yellow-green gradient, the blue-red one isn't assigned.

Comment: Update: I found a Windows 10 machine and tried on Firefox. Same issue.

Comment: Weird, I'm not seeing it (anymore?) in the snippet. I think it was my dodgy old eyes tricking me. But I did figure out the problem. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have any units on your values. `0` is a special value, it doesn't require any units, but all other values do.

Adding `px` solves the problem:

```
let gradient = 'radial-gradient(circle at ' + e.clientX + 'px ' + e.clientY + 'px, blue, red)';
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^
```

FWIW, I'd use a template literal:

```
let gradient = `radial-gradient(circle at ${e.clientX}px ${e.clientY}px, blue, red)`;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^−−−−−−−−−^^^−^^−−−−−−−−−^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('buggy-gradient');

for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
  divs.item(i).addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    let gradient = `radial-gradient(circle at ${e.clientX}px ${e.clientY}px, blue, red)`;
    console.log(gradient);
    e.target.style.background = gradient;
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background: radial-gradient(green, yellow);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class=buggy-gradient></div>
<div class=buggy-gradient></div>
<div class=buggy-gradient></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add "" to between your class name.

You can check your code working here:

[Code here](https://jsgraph.kamakepar.repl.co/try1.html)

Code:

```
<div class="buggy-gradient"> Gradient1</div>
<div class="buggy-gradient">Gradient2</div>
<div class="buggy-gradient">Gradient3</div>
<script>
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('buggy-gradient');

for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
  divs.item(i).addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    e.target.style = 'background:radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, blue, red)';
  });
  console.log('Show')
}
</script>
```

Comment: As I wrote: This works. What doesn't work for me is "let gradient = 'radial-gradient(circle at ' + e.clientX + ' ' + e.clientY + ', blue, red)';
e.target.style.background = gradient;" It isn't assigned.

Comment: *"You forgot to add "" to between your class name."* If you mean that the OP needs `"` *around* the class name, no, they don't. If there's only one class name, the `"` are entirely optional (even if the class name has a hyphen). See: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#unquoted